# Xamarin android textView scrolling does not work

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, textview, monodevelop

I have a layout with single `textview` control on it. By default `textview` is being populated on app load with large data and scrollbars for `textview` is set so that user can scroll on `textview` to see more data. I have defined `OnClick` event of `textview`, which when clicked opens Activity B.

But, When i try to scroll `textview`, it fires `OnClick` event and opens Activity B, rather than scrolling textview so that i could see more text on the screen.

Comment: Give the code you have tried....

Comment: Can you please post the **JAVA** file **XML** file?

Comment: Did you solved your problem?

Comment: By adding Main.MovementMethod = new Android.Text.Method.ScrollingMovementMethod() enabled scrolling, but click event is not working now.

Answer (score 1):

I installed on ScrollView landroid: layout_height = "wrap_content"
you can set the static height within which the will to scroll your text

```
<ScrollView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
        <TextView
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textViewClickableText"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="15sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```